# Does the mapper and reducer classes need to be deployed on all nodes of a Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Does the jar file containing my Mapper/Reducer classes need to be deployed on all nodes where Hadoop is running? Or only on the Master Node (Name Node)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer: NO.**

The `node/gateway` machine from where you start your MapReduce job. You need to put your main `MapReduce Driver` jar in the local file system and all the dependency jars can be put either into `local file system` or `HDFS` path. So when you start the job you will pass the dependency library jar path using `-libjars` parameter. The HDFS jars will contain the **`hdfs://`** prefix to their path in HDFS. The main MapReduce jar is required on the local system to start the mapreduce job, which essentially contact **Resource Manager** (Hadoop-2) for allocating application specific **Application Master** for the job.

Hadoop is designed using **Data locality** concept. In the real world, size of the data is much more than the size of the code which need to execute on the data. The executable jars are transferred to the nodes which locally contains the block of data. This minimize the network transfer time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question.

Your jar need to be locally in all the nodes that will execute at least one task (Map and/or reducer) of your job (not all nodes). **BUT** you don't need to distribute your jar by yourself. That is what hadoop know how to do based on its ResourceManager and its MapReduce framework.The **hadoop jar** command is who start that process. In case that your MapReduce application requires external dependencies (other jars) then you need to put them available to hadoop and specify them to be distributed among the nodes.